# php datetime multiple comparisons not working as expected but work individually?

Tags: php, date, datetime, if-statement, logic

I'm having issues with my if statement in that both conditions give the expected result individually but when combined so that when both are true the statement breaks.

The idea is to calculate the start date before Christmas so I can show a message about this. My logic was that by ensuring the start date is after October 1st and the end date before December 24th this message will always appear at the correct time give our start and end date schedule.

My code so far is below, there is also a dump below each variable .

```
foreach ( $events as $event ) {
    $start  =   date("d-m-Y", strtotime($event->EventStartDate));
    // string(10) "26-10-2018"
    $end    =   date("d-m-Y", strtotime($event->EventEndDate));
    // string(10) "20-12-2018"
    echo '<div id="prod-dates">';
    echo '<p>Order&nbsp;before ' . $start . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Estimated&nbsp;Delivery ' . $end . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    //
    //EVERYTHING IS FINE UNTIL HERE...
    //
    $this_christmas   =   date('Y-12-24');
    // string(10) "2018-12-24"
    $startx  =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($event->EventStartDate));
    // string(10) "2018-10-26" 
    $endx    =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime($event->EventEndDate));
    // string(10) "2018-12-20"
    $note_start       =   date('Y-11-01');
    // string(10) "2018-11-01
    if ( $startx >= $note_start || $endx <= $this_christmas ) {
        echo 'This is your last deadline for <span>Christmas&nbsp;Delivery</span>';
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "October 1st" in your description but in your code `$note_start` is set to November (2018-11-01).

You want to ensure "the start date is after October 1st and the end date before December 24th" but you check whether *either* condition is true with `if ( $startx >= $note_start || $endx <= $this_christmas )`. Replace the or (`||`) with and (`&&`).

Answer (score 1):

[date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) function returns a string value, so your dates are compared as strings.

Better use values that return **strtotime** to compare your dates

Sample:

```
$start = strtotime($event->EventStartDate);
$end = strtotime($event->EventEndDate);

//$note_start in time format
if ( $startx >= $note_start || $endx <= $this_christmas ) {
  //echo 
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've changed all to strtotime and still the same issue

Comment: @blackhill24 did you change $note_start variable? can you show how you changed it?

Comment: Dates formatted as "Y-m-d" will compare lexicographically anyway. eg "2018-12-01" is greater than "2018-11-20" when compared as a string.

Comment: For the next 7,982 years, at least :D